# How can I make images going down the screen randomly and at a certain speed (video game js)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am building a game where a spaceship moves into the screen with PC controllers. Now, my remaining part is to make a fireball images drop of the screen randomly with a precise speed and quantity (because the image is only one, we have to multiplicate it). Can someone achieve this?

**Here is the code:**

Fireball image:

```
<img src="Photo/fireball.png" id="fireball">
```

Spaceship image:

```
<img src="Photo/Spaceship1.png" id="icon-p">
```

Spaceship moving with controllers + prevent it from going out of screen:

```
let display = document.getElementById("body");
let rect = icon;
let pos = { top: 1000, left: 570 };
const keys = {};

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = true
});
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = false
});

const loop = function() {

  if (keys[37] || keys[81]) { pos.left -= 10; }
  if (keys[39] || keys[68]) { pos.left += 10; }
  if (keys[38] || keys[90]) { pos.top -= 10; }
  if (keys[40] || keys[83]) { pos.top += 10; }

  var owidth = display.offsetWidth;
  var oheight = display.offsetHeight;
  var iwidth = rect.offsetWidth;
  var iheight = rect.offsetHeight;

  if (pos.left < 0) { pos.left = -10; }
  if (pos.top < 0) { pos.top = -10; }
  if (pos.left + iwidth >= owidth) { pos.left = owidth - iwidth; }
  if (pos.top + iheight >= oheight) { pos.top = oheight - iheight; }

  rect.setAttribute("data", owidth + ":" + oheight);
  rect.style.left = pos.left + "px";
  rect.style.top = pos.top + "px";
};

let sens = setInterval(loop, 1000 / 60);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Random X coordiante
function rndScreenX(offset) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (window.innerWidth - offset));
}

// Set fireball coordinates (X is random)
let fireballElement = document.querySelector('#fireball');
let fireball = {
  x: rndScreenX(fireballElement.offsetWidth),
  y: 0
}

const loop = function() {
  // Change fireball Y
  fireball.y += 10;
  fireballElement.style.top = fireball.y + 'px';
  
  if (fireball.y > window.innerHeight) {
    // Fireball is out of window
    // Reset Y and get new random X
    fireball.x = rndScreenX(fireballElement.offsetWidth);
    fireballElement.style.left = fireball.x + 'px';
    fireball.y = 0;
  }
};

fireballElement.style.left = fireball.x + 'px';
let sens = setInterval(loop, 1000 / 60);
```

```css
#fireball {
  position: absolute;
  /* Ignore this rule if you're using an image */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 40% 40% 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<img src="Photo/fireball.png" id="fireball">
```

Comment: Just, how do I change the quantity of image which drops down from the top screen? (because actually the same image is lopped over and over... I would like to have more images dropping down the screen if possible). I would really appreciate your response.

Comment: You can do this by putting the fireball object in an array and loop over it. If you do so you can even give every fireball an own velocity, so they drop with different speed. If you do this, i would recommend creating the <img> tags with javascript aswell (document.createElement).

Answer (score 0):

This solution includes **three configurable variables: `spawnRate`, `advanceRate`, and `fallDistance`**. It uses them to determine how often new fireballs spawn, how often they move down the screen, and how far they move on each 'tick'.

**The "main" part of the script consists of two `setInterval` calls**, one to handle spawning new fireballs, and the other to handle advancing them down the screen.

(See the in-code comments for further explanation.)

```js
  const
    display = document.getElementById("display"), // Container element
    fireballs = [], // Array to hold all fireball objects

    fallDistance = 6; // Measured in `vh` units (but could be whatever)
    spawnRate = 2000,
    advanceRate = 500;

  // Adds the first fireball immediately
  spawnFireball(fireballs);

  // Moves all fireballs down every 500 milliseconds
  const advancerTimer = setInterval(
    function(){ advanceAll(fireballs, fallDistance, display); },
    advanceRate
  );

  // Spawns a new fireball every 2000 milliseconds
  const spawnerTimer = setInterval(
    function(){ spawnFireball(fireballs); },
    spawnRate
  );

  // Defines a function to add a fireball to the array
  function spawnFireball(fireballs){
    const
      img = document.createElement("img"), // Element to add to screen
      x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 96) + 2, // Random `x` position
      y = 3; // `y` position starts near top of screen
    img.src = "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.UyMqod0eO6Qcmco1Zrmj0QAAAA%26pid%3DApi&f=1",
    img.classList.add("fireball"); // To style fireballs
    img.style.left = x + "vw"; // `x` position will never change

    newFb = { x, y, img }; // `fb` object includes coords + img element
    fireballs.push(newFb); // Adds the new fireball to the array
  }

  // Defines a function to advance a fireball's position
  function advance(fb, distance){
    fb.y += distance; 
  }

  // Defines a function to draw a fireball in the container
  function draw(fb, container){
    if(fb.y > 100){ return; } // Ignores below-screen fireballs
    fb.img.style.top = fb.y + "vh"; // Updates the location on screen
    container.appendChild(fb.img); // The `img` property holds our DOM element
  }

  // Defines a function to advance and draw all fireballs
  function advanceAll(fireballs, distance, container){
    for(let fb of fireballs){
      advance(fb, distance);
      draw(fb, container)
    }
  }
```

```css
#display{ height: 99vh; width: 99vw; position: relative; }
.fireball{ height: 2em; width: 2em; position: absolute; }
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: In real life, you probably want to use `window.requestAnimationFrame` for the draw updates, and `transform` property for movement, for performance reasons (which includes battery life)

Comment: Thanks. I don't deal with animations in real life, which is why those methods didn't end up in my answer. But now Thomas can incorporate them based on their reference articles on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) if the game will be used in production.